# What causes typescript compile error when deploying

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I roughly following this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0) to make a cloud function with typescript. It works fine in development, but when I try to deploy it (firebase deploy --only functions), I get A LOT of typescript errors. I have no idea why. It works in dev, why can't I push the same set up to Firebase?

Comment: I am sure you are running into ESlint errors : "parserOptions.project has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser”. Have a look at my answer below for the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps for a successful cloud functions deployment:

- After you have created a Firebase project using this [step](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0#create-a-firebase-project), install
  the Firebase CLI using : `npm install -g firebase-tools`.
- Run `firebase login` to log in via the browser and authenticate the
  firebase tool.
- Run `firebase init firestore`
- Run `firebase init functions`
- When you run `firebase init functions`, there will be prompts, 1st
  prompt : “What language would you like to use to write Cloud
  Functions?” -> Choose Typescript. 2nd prompt : Do you want to use
  ESlint to catch probable bugs and enforce style (y/n)? -> Choose n.
  By selecting no you will be saving yourself from the typescript
  compile errors.
- Once initialization is complete, uncomment the sample in index.ts and
  run `npm run serve` to see a "Hello World" function in action. Once you
  can see the output in Firebase emulator, you will know the functions
  executed properly.
- Now, before you deploy the functions, assign the Cloud Functions
  Invoker, Cloud Functions Admin and Cloud Functions Developer role to
  project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
- Now run `firebase deploy –only functions`. The deployment will be
  successful but the browser might show 403 errors ( Client does not
  have permission..) For that, select your cloud function (check box)
  click "Add members" under the Permissions tab in the right side,
  enter "allUsers" under "New members", select Role as `Cloud Functions -> Cloud Functions Invoker` and then save the configuration.
- If you do not want to give public access to your cloud functions, you
  can set up authentication, by skipping the previous step. In Cloud
  Shell, run `gcloud auth print-identity-token`. This outputs a token
  which you will be authenticating your cloud function with. Now
  provide authentication credentials in your request as a
  Google-generated ID token stored in an Authorization header with this
  command :

`curl https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME \  -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"`